# How to show future events with organizer_list_events on the EventBrite API

Tags: eventbrite

I always get ended events from the eventBrite api when i use the organizer_list_events.  I tried with statuses live, started (and both).  But that doesn't seem to work.

The event_search api has a "date:Future" possibility.  Which is working fine, but then I don't have a possibility to pass the organiserId.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note, I work on the platform team at Eventbrite

`organizer_list_events` does not accept a `status` parameter:

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/organizers/organizer_list_events/

However, `user_list_events` does:

http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/users/user_list_events/

In the case that one user has one organizer, these calls should return the same data.  It's possible for one user to have multiple organizers, in which case `user_list_events` could return more data than needed.  Still, using the `status` parameter should cut down on what you're currently receiving.

We're in the process of building a new and much improved API, but I can look at adding a `status` field to `organizer_list_events`.

Comment: Hi.  I've been looking to the account.  They have indeed 2 organizers under 1 user account.  A status field for the organizer_list_events would be the most obvious solution.

Comment: Hey @brianz, I wonder why the sample code at EventBrite (http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/widgets/#list) indicates that organizer_list_events _can_ infact be passed status parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Using the user_list_events I just did this (in c#):

```
items = XElement.Parse(xmlResult).Elements("event").Where(e=>e.Element("organizer").Element("id").Value == this.OrganiserId.ToString());
```