# Showing only future events with eventbrite api

Tags: api, eventbrite

I'm having trouble using the EventBrite API. The following code is currently outputting the title, date, time and location. However it's giving all events ever created by that organiser.

I've tried experimenting with other params on organizer_list_events to no avail.

The example code is from here: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/widgets/#list

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        Eventbrite({'app_key': "XKPRFJAIRCOM5IB4KK"}, function(eb){
            var eb_options = {
                'id' : 2164293743
            };
            eb.organizer_list_events( eb_options, function( response ){
                var eventbrite_list = eb.utils.eventList( response, eb.utils.eventListRow );
                jQuery("#eventbrite-list").html(eventbrite_list);
                console.log(response);  
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the Python client, which seems to ignore almost every parameter I pass to it.

Comment: For anyone with the same problem on the front end I ended up just fildering them by date with JS as it was quicker than getJSON etc.

Comment: I got mine working just leveraging the requests library in Python and filtering .user_list_events() with `event_statuses='live,started'

Answer (score 2):

A similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15765021/303659) was answered by someone at Eventbrite who claims that the `status` parameter is not available for `organizer_list_events`.

If you don't have more than one organizer profile in your Eventbrite account, you can use `user_list_events` instead, with the email address of your account:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    Eventbrite({'app_key': "XKPRFJAIRCOM5IB4KK"}, function(eb){
      // NEW CODE
        var eb_options = {
            'user' : 'email@address.abc',
            'event_statuses' : 'live, started'
        };
        eb.user_list_events( eb_options, function( response ){
      // END NEW CODE
            var eventbrite_list = eb.utils.eventList( response, eb.utils.eventListRow );
            jQuery("#eventbrite-list").html(eventbrite_list);
            console.log(response);  
        });
    });
});
```